# Regex pattern to find and replace IMG src

Tags: html, regex, replace

I am trying to create a regex pattern to find and then replace my IMG src tags in my HTML template.

Essentially, the pattern should find the contents of the src:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/img/building.jpg" />
```

And then replace it as such:

```
<img src="http://www.domain.com/image/timthumb.php?src=http://www.domain.com/img/building.jpg&w=800" />
```

I essentially need to append to the beginning and end of the existing src attribute.

What would be the pattern to find and then the pattern to replace?

Comment: use the [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Parsing HTML using Regex is painful.

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: I'm definitely stuck using regex for HTML. I'm in a CMS which has an addon that allows me to input a regex pattern string for "search" and then another for "replace".

Comment: What is this regex plugin, and do you know what flavour of regex it use?

Comment: The plugin is for Expression Engine and you can find the informational on it at: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace/docs (simple page) as for the flavor, i'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
your_string.replace(/(<img\ssrc=")(.*?)("\s?\/>)/, "$1http://www.domain.com/image/timthumb.php?src=$2&w=800$3");
```

Example:

```
> '<img src="http://www.domain.com/img/building.jpg" />'.replace(/(<img\ssrc=")(.*?)("\s?\/>)/, "$1http://www.domain.com/image/timthumb.php?src=$2&w=800$3")
"<img src="http://www.domain.com/image/timthumb.php?src=http://www.domain.com/img/building.jpg&w=800" />"
```

Comment: Ok, forgive me. I am using a bit of CMS template code which can perform a regex and I can simply enter in the pattern for find="" replace="". How would I likely seperate out your regex in a scenario like that?

Comment: I would guess find is `"(<img\\ssrc=\")(.*?)(\"\\s?\\/>)"` and replace is `"$1http://www.domain.com/image/timthumb.php?src=$2&w=800$3`.

Comment: I think this is better `/(<img\ssrc=\")(.*?)(\"\s.*?>)/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with that:

```
find="(<img\b(?:[^s>]+|\Bs|s(?!rc\s*=\s*))+src\s*=\s*)[\"']?((http:\/\/)?([^\/]+)\/(?:[^\/\s]+\/)*)([^\"'\s>]+)[\"']?"
replace="$1\"$3$4/image/timthumb.php?src=$2&w=800\""
```

Comment: That did not seem to work. I'm sure there is a parsing error with two " at the end of the replace.

Comment: the problem is that the pattern and the replacement must be surrounded by double quotes (cf: the doc). I have escape all the double quotes in the pattern and in the replacement string, but I don't know how the double quotes must be escaped to work with the plugin. In the worst scenario, you have perhaps the possibility to replace each double quotes (and remove backslashes) with an unicode equivalent: `\u0021`

Comment: Or replace each `"` with `QUOTE`